# How to get variable length placeholders in a Python call to SQLite3

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way to use variable length placeholders in an SQL query?

Right now with a 3-tuple, I write something like this:

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE word IN (?, ?, ?)', tup)
```

But what if the *tup* can be of differing lengths, perhaps a 4-tuple or 2-tuple?  Is there a syntax for using placeholders in this situation?  If not, what is the preferred way to write the code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd have to do something like this (to use your example):

```
tup = ... # some sequence/tuple of unknown length
sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE word IN (%s)' % ', '.join('?' for a in tup)
c.execute(sql, tup)
```

This way you're dynamically creating the placeholder list and formatting the SQL string before the sqlite3 module parses it out.

Comment: I had hoped there was ?? or ?* variant for this sort of thing, but your suggestion will do nicely.

Comment: I'd write `', '.join('?' for a in tup)` as `', '.join('?'*len(tup))`

Comment: @Duncan: Idunno that seems less clear to me more signal noise. The generator comprehension seems to read more like english

Comment: Would ``'SELECT * FROM table WHERE word IN (%s)' % (len(tup) * '?, ')`` work , or the last comma isn't accepted in an SQL query ?

Comment: I expect @eyquem has figured this out by now, but for the sake of completeness: No, the trailing comma is not syntactically valid here, though this [may vary by implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11387549/2359271) (as usual for SQL).