# Why doesn't a trailing comma after the last field matter when creating a table using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

Shouldn't one of these statements work and one fail?

Intuition says **Statement 2** should fail because there is a comma after **int** and no second column listed.

Yet both work and the trailing comma "," after the last column data type makes no difference.

```
-- Statement 1
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable1( col1 int);

-- Statement 2
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2( col1 int,);
```

However (and this is expected): two commas ",," after the last field do cause a failure:

```
-- Statement 3
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable3( col1 int,,);

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Testing shows that its not just any character after the last field that is allowed through. For example, this fails:

```
-- Statement 3
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable3( col1 int ~);

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '~'.
```

Maybe SQL Server is "saving a seat at the table" for something? The Primary Key perhaps? I really don't know.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64).

Comment: I assume that it's a design decision to ease dynamic sql, when you don't have to omit the comma. Similar to why LINQ allows such an anonymous type in C#: `new {a=1,b=2,c=3,}`.

Comment: Shouldn't be allowed by [the grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) but [mostly harmless](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273348/trailing-comma-allowed-in-create-table)

Comment: @Martin Smith: That depends, if n in the diagram is including 0 or not. The syntax contains no definition (at least none I found).

Comment: I find it quite useful (can easily comment out columns when testing if they all have a trailing comma) but it is acknowledged as a bug on connect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273348/trailing-comma-allowed-in-create-table:

> **Description**
>
> When executing the CREATE TABLE command, a trailing comma following
>   the last column is allowed. Based on the grammar in BOL and comma
>   usage in lists in other T-SQL statements, this behavior is
>   inconsistent. This is a very minor issue and does not appear to cause
>   any adverse side-effects. It just appears that the parser may be a bit
>   off.

Microsoft views this as a bug, but a minor one.

> This was resolved some time ago as "won't fix" but we didn't explain why. Simply, this seems pretty harmless, and not worth fixing in a service pack. We may consider fixing this in a future release.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all languages which permit comma-separated list items permit a comma after the last list item. This is done to make editing the program or file, and especially inserting new list items, easier. You don't have to worry about adding a comma after the current last list item, or removing a comma if you delete the old last list item.

Comment: SQL Server generally doesn't though. If it was intentional allowing an extra trailing comma in an `IN` list would probably be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

It should be flagged as a syntax error, but there is a bug in SQL Server that doesn't treat the trailing comma as a syntax error.

Source: [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161592) (The affected versions in the list - 6, 6.5, and 2000 - are old, but I guess it's still around because it just worked for me in 2008.)