# Dynamically creating a placeholder to insert many column values for a row in SQLite table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, dynamic, tuples

I know that it's possible to insert many column values in a SQLite database using a variable with a tuple of values `('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00)` and a corresponding placeholder `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` in the query string. I am creating the value tuples dynamically in my program and they may hold up to ~300 values. I am wondering if there is a safe (with respect to SQL injection attacks) way to dynamically generate corresponding the placeholder tuple string `(?, ?, ?, ...)` for the query string? I ask this to avoid tediously counting, adding and deleting `?`s as my database structure and value tuples change throughout development. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a string based on the number of items in your `values`, eg:

```
def place_holder(values):
    return '({})'.format(', '.join('?' * len(values)))

values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ph = place_holder(values)
# (?, ?, ?)
```

Then something like:

```
your_cursor.execute('insert into your_table values {}'.format(ph), values)
```

If it doesn't meet your schema, you'll have issues, but that's another problem...

Comment: I just noticed this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/q/7991183/2441384] here as well - I have such a function. I was wondering if concatenating this to the query string before passing it to `execute()` is robust to SQL injection attacks? The other answer seems to imply so. I wonder then why bother with placeholders?

Comment: @gromiczek Because you're responsible for creating the place holder string, you know it's safe... the un-safe bit is from the `values` themselves, and that part will still be escaped/handled properly. Where most people fall down is trying to put the `values` into the query string... it's fine to create your own place holder string to accommodate the necessary things (table name/placeholders/etc...) required for your query string.

Comment: @JonClements I was trying your idea with the following post, and it's not working.  would you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727201/python-sqlite3-record-is-not-inserting-into-the-database-with-a-placeholder-func and see why i can't insert the list info although i have no error after I run the script?