# How to programatically set the amount of parameters in python sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

When there are only a few parameters I can do this

```
cur.execute(INSERT INTO table (col1,col2) VALUES (?,?), (1,2))
```

but what if I have like 50 parameters? I don't want to write 50 question marks in that case. Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
cur.execute(INSERT INTO table (listOfColumns) VALUES tuple(['?']*len(listOfColumns)), (listOfValues))
```

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991183/how-to-get-variable-length-placeholders-in-a-python-call-to-sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just build the SQL statement dynamically:

```
sql = ('INSERT INTO table ({}) VALUES ({})'.format(','.join(listOfColumns),
     ','.join('?'*len(listOfColumns))))
cur.execute(sql, listOfValues)
```

Note that this assumes the list of columns was generated locally and not tainted by user input. If the list of columns could be tainted you need to check it pretty carefully to ensure that it only contains valid column names before inserting it into SQL code.